# How to fix error while exporting from blender to mogre/ogre (.mesh and .scene format)?

Tags: blender, ogre

I've been trying to export a blender object with a texture using blender2OGRE (https://code.google.com/p/blender2ogre/)

I go to export->OGRE3D (.mesh .scene), and it begins the export. it then triggers a break point with the following log

```
Error
Traceback(most recent call last):
File"/home/team/.config/blender/2.65/scripts/addons/io_export_ogreDotScene.py", line 3159, in execute self.ogre_export(Self.filepath, context)
File"/home/team/.config/blender/2.65/scripts/addons/io_export_ogreDotScene.py", line 3514, in ogre_export_material_files = self.dot_material(meshes + force_matrial_update, path, matherial_file_name_base)
File"/home/team/.config/blender/2.65/scripts/addons/io_export_ogreDotScene.py", line 3356,in dot_material_data = generate_material(mat, path=path, copy_programs = true, touch_textures=CONFIG('TOUCH_TEXTURES'))
File"/home/team/.config/blender/2.65/scripts/addons/io_export_ogreDotScene.py", line 6993, in generate_material_passes = w.get_passes()
File"/home/team/.config/blender/2.65/scripts/addons/io_export_ogreDotScene.py", line 3349, in get_passes_r.append(Self.generate_pass(self.material))
File"/home/team/.config/blender/2.65/scripts/addons/io_export_ogreDotScene.py", line 6677, in_generate_pass if slote.texture.use_alpha: usealpha = True; break
AttributeError: 'ImageTexture' object has no attribute 'use alpha'
location:<unknown location>
```

It appears to be trying to assign a value to a variable which doesn't exist.

If someone could shed some light on this issue, I would be very appreciative

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things ...

1. Looking at the script in the [Google Code repo](https://code.google.com/p/blender2ogre/source/browse/io_export_ogreDotScene.py#6677), it appears that
   line 6677 has been changed to `if slot.texture.use_alpha: usealpha =
   True; break`. Note that the error output you provided has "slot"
   spelled as "slote". I would update to the latest revision of the
   script and see if that fixes it.
2. If that fails, check out
   [Python AttributeError: Object has no attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685936/python-attributeerror-object-has-no-attribute).
   Running `python -tt` on
   `/home/team/.config/blender/2.65/scripts/addons/io_export_ogreDotScene.py`
   will tell you if indentation is the problem.

If you don't see any indentation errors, then I'd file a bug report against the project on Google Code.