# multiprocessing inside exec command

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I need to use multiprocessing in a piece of code which is injected as string into `exec` function:

```
code = """
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print('hello', name)

p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
p.start()
p.join()
"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
   exec(code)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Programming\WinPython-64bit-3.3.5.0\python-3.3.5.amd64\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 351, in main
self = load(from_parent)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'f'
```

I am very new to multiprocessing... and I must say I have no idea what is wrong. My system is Windows 7 64-bit.

UPDATE: ... and a more general question: is it possible to run a user defined script (stored in a string) asynchronously in another process? This is actually what I try to achieve.

Comment: This must be windows specific. Your code works on mac/linux python 2.7 and 3.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`multiprocessing` **requires** that the `target` function be importable by subprocesses from your `__main__` module.  Here, said module defines no `f`, therefore the constraint is not met (even though some operating systems manage to let you relax the constraint, it's terrible practice, and kills the portability of your code).

I would recommend analyzing the `code` string, e.g via the `compile` built-in, and ensuring a `__main__`-level definition of the required `target`.

Comment: I am not sure if I fully understand what it means. Is there a way I can make it work just by changing the contents of the string in variable `code`? Suppose I cannot change anything outside of it.

Comment: No, unless you can set `f` as a global attribute of `__main__`, which exclusively changing the string `code` per se cannot do, then you can't make the whole code reliable for `multiprocessing` across all Python implementations.

Comment: OK, bad luck for me. :( I have to find a workaround for my problem. I have started playing with Pool and apply_async and put the multiprocessing ability outsize of the code string... seems promising so far.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be running into the same indentation problem as seen here: [Python AttributeError: Object has no attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685936/python-attributeerror-object-has-no-attribute)  Try ensuring that your print and exec lines are properly tabbed.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old issue...   In any case, the following works:

```
script = """
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
"""
exec(script)
```