# unable to get python -tt script.py to work to diagnose AttributeError

Tags: python

I am getting an `AttributeError` when trying to call a class in python. I saw this excellent post on diagnosing it:

[Python AttributeError: Object has no attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685936/python-attributeerror-object-has-no-attribute).

However when I enter the diagnostic command that was suggested in the post with the following command

```
python -tt script.py
```

into a cell into my jupyter notebook it then returns:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Can someone tell me how to modify this command so it works in a jupyter notebook and returns what I am doing wrong?

Comment: That's a command you call from the shell, not from inside Python. But all it will do is check if you have any indents that mix spaces and tabs.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  How do I access the python shell to use this command?

Comment: As I just said, you don't do it in Python; I was referring to your computer's command line terminal. I can't help you access that, I'm afraid.